# How to perform benchmarking in scheme?

Tags: scheme, benchmarking, chicken-scheme

I am looking to test various Scheme constructs for comparison purposes and was wondering how to go about doing so. I know Ruby has a dedicate module for such benchmarking and a web search does not appear to readily provide a Scheme version. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of such a facility? If it matters, I am using Chicken Scheme.

Comment: You may be able to use the `salmonella` egg to do this.  http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/salmonella

Answer (score 1):

If you're after something really basic, you can use the [`time` special form](http://api.call-cc.org/doc/chicken/special-forms#def%3atime).

Answer (score 0):

You can compile a program using -profile, then when you run it it will write a profiling file. This can then be analysed with the `chicken-profile` program.

This is documented in the ["using the compiler" section](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Using%20the%20compiler) of the manual (search for `-profile`).